# Mounting outlet to rubble stone wall

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm looking to mount an outlet to this rubble stone wall. The wiring would come down from the ceiling. I was thinking of trying to screw a conduit to the stone wall to house the wiring but the wall is a bit uneven. Is there another way?

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell just how uneven that is, can you see add a profile pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 4-square metal box. Use any common masonry anchors. Anchor into rock not mortar. Half inch ENT (electrical non-metallic tubing) would be a good choice for conduit.  You can use the ENT as a sleeve for the NM cable. Use a 1/2" raised cover and a standard receptacle. You will need a small hammer drill to drill holes in the rock and rock bit. Support the ENT every couple of feet. P.